# Dropbox Referrer Bonus not applied

Tags: dropbox

I have a problem with Dropbox bonus for contacts' referral. I have a PC running Ubuntu and since my Mother and my Father use the laptop very scarcely I simply added 2 users for them, so I have on the same PC the followings;

- me
- mother
- father

Now I had the necessity to give some files to my Father and the first thing that came to my mind was to use Dropbox. So I invited him and configured his account to use Dropbox. I gave him the files and all works fine but the famous Dropbox bonus! In fact I didn't get any 500MB for the new Dropbox user I referred.

Is this because the user is on the same machine I am? Is there some error of mine?

Comment: You're better off contacting Dropbox support directly. Be patient as it may take them a week to reply.

Comment: I had this happen too when I referred my father. I sent them an e-mail or clicked the appeal link (I seem to recall there was one) and got my referral bonus an hour later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is because you used the same computer.

This is covered by the explanation of the [different Dropbox referral statuses](https://www.dropbox.com/help/56):

> **Ineligible** means that the recipient is ineligible for the referral program. Either they have already registered an account with Dropbox or are **attempting to register using the same computer as you**. These restrictions are intended to prevent people from gaming the system (cheating). If you feel you this status is inaccurate or applied unfairly, double-check the email address of your recipient and try again.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, what do you mean by ''double-check the email address of your recipient and try again'' ?

Comment: It's not me saying that: I'm quoting from the Dropbox website. The bit that is relevant to you is the text I highlighted. However, what they mean about double-checking email the address is that if you invited someone (on a different computer), and the referral didn't work, then check whether you entered their email address correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did not get the 500MB, although I referred to my husband to Dropbox and made sure he installs.  I figured it out.

So, what I did was:

Go online with Dropbox.

Go to Sharing.

On top of the screen on the right side of my User Name, I click on the icon "Get free space!".

Next page I click on: "Refer friends to Dropbox"

On the bottom of the Referrals Page (https://www.dropbox.com/referrals) there is a sentence: "Once you've invited friends, you can view the status of your referrals or visit our Help Center if you have any questions."

Click on the hyperlink: "view the status of your referrals"

I see the status of all my invites, but no bonus.  I refresh the screen.  Nothing.

I see that the Bonus type "Getting Started".  I click on the link and complete "The Dropbox Tour".

After I come back to the referral status page.  I see I received 250MB for doing the tour and 500MB for my husbands installed Dropbox.